# ConvertTo-Json formatting

Tags: powershell

Running the following:

```
Get-Process | Select-Object Id,ProcessName,CPU,StartTime | ConvertTo-Json
```

And the resulting JSON shows the StartTime as:

```
"\/Date(1553511537485)\/"
```

How can I show the StartTime in a given date format please?

Comment: See: Calculated properties section of the `Select-Object` documentation on msdn.

Answer (score 3):

Try piping through something like this, which has the benefit of handling datetimes with unknown property names:

```bsh
foreach-object {$_.Psobject.properties | foreach-object {if ($_.value -ne $null -and $_.value.gettype() -match '.*datetime'){$_.value=$_.value.toString("o")}};$_}
```

E.g. for the original question:

```bsh
Get-Process | Select-Object Id,ProcessName,CPU,StartTime | foreach-object {$_.Psobject.properties | foreach-object {if ($_.value -ne $null -and $_.value.gettype() -match '.*datetime'){$_.value=$_.value.toString("o")}};$_} | convertto-json
```

Here StartTime is a datetime field, and so it converted to an ISO date in the output JSON.

```
    {
        "Id":  7192,
        "ProcessName":  "ZeroConfigService",
        "CPU":  19.703125,
        "StartTime":  "2020-04-20T16:59:44.1843370+01:00"
    }
```

...instead of:

```
    {
        "Id":  7192,
        "ProcessName":  "ZeroConfigService",
        "CPU":  19.71875,
        "StartTime":  "\/Date(1587398384184)\/"
    }
```

A similar approach can work for database results, where the field names might not be known:

```bsh
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SELECT GETDATE() AS TimeOfQuery, getDate() anotherDate,'test' string" -ServerInstance "localhost" | Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty ItemArray, Table, RowError, RowState, HasErrors | convertto-json
```

...gives:

```
{
    "TimeOfQuery":  "\/Date(1587646812587)\/",
    "anotherDate":  "\/Date(1587646812587)\/",
    "string":  "test"
}
```

Whereas this:

```bsh
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "SELECT GETDATE() AS TimeOfQuery, getDate() anotherDate,'test' string" -ServerInstance "localhost" | Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty ItemArray, Table, RowError, RowState, HasErrors | foreach-object {$_.Psobject.properties | foreach-object {if ($_.value -ne $null -and $_.value.gettype() -match '.*datetime'){$_.value=$_.value.toString("o")}};$_} | convertto-json
```

...gives ISO formatted dates:

```
{
    "TimeOfQuery":  "2020-04-23T13:53:59.1230000",
    "anotherDate":  "2020-04-23T13:53:59.1230000",
    "string":  "test"
}
```

The date format can be changed by changing the parameter of the getString method `toString("o")`. "o" is for ISO date format.  See (I think) under examples at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring for details.

Note that the select-object in the pipeline is necessary, otherwise the foreach-object clause will attempt to update the properties of the original object, which may be read-only, and you probably don't want to do. (Does anybody know a better method for this?)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a calculated property to perform the `.ToString` method on `StartTime` which would convert it to its default string format equivalent:

```
Get-Process | Select-Object Id,ProcessName,CPU,@{N='StartTime';E={$_.StartTime.ToString()}}| ConvertTo-Json
```

Example result:

```
 "StartTime":  "23/03/2019 08:55:06"
```

Comment: You can also customize the `ToString()` with specific format e.g.: `ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")`

Comment: @Avshalom Or just pass a format string `.ToString('o')` for UTC.